# Port forwarding out multiple VLAN interfaces that have same IP address

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, port-forwarding

So I have an Ubuntu machine with multiple VLAN on an interface eth1 and each VLAN has the same IP address (172.16.0.2). I need to be able to simultaneously telnet into a rack of devices that are also the same IP (172.16.0.1). The only way I can think of to do this is through IPtables forwarding traffic to specific destination ports out a particular interface.

for example I want to be able to run "telnet 172.16.0.1 12001" and have this go out interface eth1.101 directed to 172.16.0.1:23 or run "telnet 172.16.0.1 12002" and have this go out interface eth1.102 directed to 172.16.0.1:23.

I've tried quite a few iptables setups with no success yet. Are there any iptables gurus who could assist in such a setup?

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:85:22:be  
          inet addr:10.0.152.86  Bcast:10.0.152.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca60:ff:fe85:22be/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:399596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:416603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:55610834 (55.6 MB)  TX bytes:562660002 (562.6 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:16:f6:72  
          inet addr:172.16.0.2  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe16:f672/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:95 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8580 (8.5 KB)  TX bytes:11943374 (11.9 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:febe0000-fec00000 

eth1.101  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:16:f6:72  
          inet addr:171.16.0.2  Bcast:171.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe16:f672/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3222 (3.2 KB)  TX bytes:24388 (24.3 KB)

eth1.102  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:16:f6:72  
          inet addr:171.16.0.2  Bcast:171.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe16:f672/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:78 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3268 (3.2 KB)  TX bytes:11718 (11.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5010 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:5010 (5.0 KB)


user@machine ~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.152.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.152.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
171.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1.101
171.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1.102
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: Whay you use the same ip address on all interfaces?

Comment: The devices we're communicating with are embedded devices with the same IP address. It doesn't really matter if they're all the same IP or not. They are part of the same subnet which causes routing issues because anything going to 172.16.0.0/24 goes out the first interface.